# Get next and previous records within the same query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having this PDO query to call data from a MySQL.

```
$sql = "SELECT itemName FROM furniture WHERE itemID = :item";
```

While calling for this particular itemName, is it possible to get the next and previous itemNames by using its itemID within this same query itself without having to write a new query to get the next and previous itemNames?

e.g. 
if

```
itemID   |   itemName
___________________________
553      |   Mahogani Black Chair
554      |   Teak Round Table
555      |   Thulang Relaxing Chair
556      |   Teak Relaxing Chair

$sql = "SELECT itemName FROM furniture WHERE itemID = :item";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':item'=>"554"));
$rslt = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I'm looking away of getting `Teak Round Table` and `Mahogani Black Chair` and `Thulang Relaxing Chair`

Comment: where itemID in(id1,id2,id3)....

Comment: @user1844933 thanks. Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT itemName FROM furniture WHERE itemID not in (554)";

if you like this mans display the all the ids other than the 554

Comment: @Becky like this you want

Comment: @Ramki thanks. I don't think that will work. Coz there are about 230 records in the db. The above example is for demonstrative purpose only.

Comment: you need to display after and before only one record or all the records

Comment: @Ramki 1 record after AND 1 record before AND ofcourse the middle record. See my above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
(SELECT itemName FROM furniture WHERE itemID < 554 order by itemID desc limit 1) 
UNION
(SELECT itemName FROM furniture WHERE itemID >= 554 order by itemID asc limit 2)
```

For Example code :

```
MyTable:
================
id  Store_name
================
1   English
2   French
3   Tamil
4   Uk
5   US

<?php  
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","ramki","ramki");
$sql = "(SELECT store_name FROM store WHERE id < 2 order by id desc limit 1) 
        UNION
        (SELECT store_name FROM store WHERE id >= 2 order by id asc limit 2)";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo $row['store_name'];
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT itemName FROM furniture WHERE itemID IN (:item-1, :item, :item+1) ORDER BY itemID";
```

For iterating the results, you can also use [PDO fetch() function](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) to get each row.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can execute the same code you demonstrated above, by just changing the $sql query variable with this one.

Comment: I've done that. I'm hgavving issues assigning the returned values in to 2 variables within the `foreach()` loop?

Comment: Can you show to do this? `foreach ($rslt as $val) { $val1 = $val["item-1"]; $val2 = $val["item-2"]; $val3 = $val["item-3"]; }` ?

Comment: You will not use fetchAll(), you will use fetch() in a for loop. Read the docs above!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. As you can see in my post I've used `fetchAll()` ( I know that `fetch()` is a better option for this requiremnt ). But what I need to know is how to assign the results in to DIFFERENT variables.

Comment: Just like retrieving a row from a normal array in PHP. `$val1 = $rslt[0]["itemName"]`